# Animating slide show in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

Anybody have any idea how this is done?

http://youtu.be/r_cII4_aq_A

In general, the idea is awesome, but I would like to know how to do each specific thing. In the video, the pages are being swiped too fast so you can't see, but as you transition from one page to the next, each pixel smoothly transitions to it's new color. Also, it's really cool how the icon gets smaller to a minimum size as you transition away from a screen.

Maybe there's some 3rd party library that provides a protocol and it's relatively easy to implement, but I can't find it. If there's not, I'm thinking it's just one view controller with many views side by side and as you drag your finger, it calculates where each view needs to be..and what color every pixel needs to be.

Comment: This stuff is all done with UIScrollViews. UIScrollViews have super-powers in iOS 7.

Comment: So it's a horizontal scroller?

Comment: Yes, and the deltaX controls the alpha of the background image and the size of the icon/text. Fun stuff. Edit: and by deltaX I mean the variation between the page rest position and the current offset.

Comment: How does it "land" on screens and not just scroll to a point in between screens?

Comment: `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you already have it by now. But in case you still have any doubts, I made gist that does the animation: https://gist.github.com/mnmaraes/9536364

Anyways, have fun.

Comment: thanks a ton, i like the lazy initialization of the second view controller

Answer (score 0):

It's a fade animation, so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                 animations:^{
    _backgroundImageView.image = nextImage;
} completion:nil];
```

should do the trick for the background part.

For the foreground/icon part you can animate the transform to scale and translate the views as they slide in and out.

Comment: I don't think it's so simple...you can drag half way and then stop and all the pixels will be half transitioned between one image and the other...

Comment: You can also manually adjust the alpha of each image while dragging if you need to maintain the "half-swiped" behavior.  That's all a dissolve animation is really is just reducing the alpha of the old image to 0 while you increase the alpha of the new image to 1.

Comment: It's hard to see in the video because the swipe is too fast, but if you swipe slowly, the images fade slowly, the pixels change at a rate dependent on how fast your finger moves...and if you drag less than half way to the next screen, it'll go back to previous screen

Comment: Just set the alphas of the two images relative to the swipe position then.  When the touch ends, figure out which image should be displayed and animate the rest of the transition.